# Get rid of uncaught errors when resolving a promise

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following method

```
export abstract class BaseCalculator {
  /**
   * Compute the promise parameter.
   * @param name name of the parameter.
   * @param method promise to resolve.
   * @returns CalculatorResult.
   */
  public async computeParameter(name: string, method: Promise<string | number | boolean | ParamString>): Promise<CalculatorResult> {
    try {
      return Promise.resolve(method)
        .then(
          (computedValue: string | number | boolean | ParamString) =>
            this.getCalculatorResult(name, computedValue)
        )
        .catch((e: string | CalculatorError) => ({ // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
          name: name,
          value: e instanceof CalculatorError ? e.value : NaN,
          error: e instanceof CalculatorError ? e : new CalculatorError(name, NaN, ErrorLevel.ERROR, e)
        } as CalculatorResult));
    }
    catch (e) { // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
      return {
        name: name,
        value: e instanceof CalculatorError ? e.value : NaN,
        error: e instanceof CalculatorError ? e : new CalculatorError(name, NaN, ErrorLevel.ERROR, String(e))
      } as CalculatorResult;
    }
  }
```

I surround it with try/catch two times, one external, the second on promise.resolve, however I still get the uncatched errors when executing the `method`s passed as parameter to that `computeParameter` function.

[image]

could someone explain how to capture **all** the thrown errors when executing such async functions?

bellow is some code that ends to be called by one of the methods I pass in parameter

```
export function displayMessage(field: string, value: any, message: string, errorLevel: ErrorLevel): void {
  throw new CalculatorError(field, value, errorLevel, message)
}

export async function checkAngleSTR(
  STA: EnumSTA,
  KUNIT: number,
  STR: number,
  NEDSF: number,
  BFL: number,
  HFL: number,
  FCTM: number,
): Promise<void> {

  let ac: number = BFL * HFL;

  switch (STA) {
    case EnumSTA.EN1992_1_1_BS:
    case EnumSTA.EN1992_2_BS:
    case EnumSTA.EN_1992_3_BS:
      if (STR < 21.8 || STR > 45) {
        displayMessage("STR", NaN, "L'angle d'inclinaison de la bielle doit être compris entre 21.8° et 45°", ErrorLevel.ERROR);
      }
      break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `.then`/`.catch` in a function tagged `async` (and never use `await` in that function) - this *may* be why errors slip between the cracks

So, either make computeParameter like this

(note, no `async` here, since `await` is never used)

```
computeParameter(name, method) {
    return method
        .then((computedValue) => this.getCalculatorResult(name, computedValue))
        .catch(e) => ({
            name,
            value: e instanceof CalculatorError ? e.value : NaN,
            error: e instanceof CalculatorError ? e : new CalculatorError(name, NaN, ErrorLevel.ERROR, e)
        }));
    }
```

or ... using `async`/`await`

```
async computeParameter(name, method) {
    try {
        const computedValue = await method;
        return this.getCalculatorResult(name, computedValue);
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            name,
            value: e instanceof CalculatorError ? e.value : NaN,
            error: e instanceof CalculatorError ? e : new CalculatorError(name, NaN, ErrorLevel.ERROR, e)
        };
    }
}
```

I've removed the "typescript" syntax to make the code clearer, and, as you say, typescript is irrelevant to the issue

Using either of these, the error thrown by `displayMessage` should now be correctly caught and handled

Comment: the cause was that, I had an async function, and not used await, so the exception was trown in another thread I suppose

Comment: no - javascript has no other thread

Comment: if has no other thread, why removed "async" helped?

Comment: @serge - you have to be careful when you mix async/await with .then/.catch - things like failing to handle rejections crop up if done incorrectly - I haven't analysed your code to determine why your code fails to handle rejections, as I don't care. Perhaps with your new found knowledge, you could do that.

Comment: to be "careful" not sure if helps, but removed async really helped.

Comment: I have had code that uses a mix, I was careful, it worked